# Windows Security Dialog and Default Credential Provider

Tags: windows, authentication, credentials, credential-providers

Windows has the ability to set which Credential Provider is used by default.  This can be set either by Group Policy (You place the text SID of the provider in "Assign a default credential provider" under Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon ) or editing the Policy in the registry by setting the string value of "**DefaultCredentialProvider**" under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System

This works in the secure desktop when unlocking a system or logging on.  However, they does not work when the Credential Providers are enumerated by the Windows Security Dialog that can be called programmatically using **CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials**.

Is there a way to set which Credential Provider is presented by the **Windows Security Dialog** as the default either when calling CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials or through some Windows Policy or registry setting?

Comment: Have a look at `ICredentialProviderFilter` interface and it's neighbours [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nn-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderfilter).

Comment: My understanding is that ICredentialProviderFilter can be used to remove Credential Providers so they are not enumerated.  It does not allow you to set which Provider will be presented as default.

Comment: You can filter out other providers and "There can be only one!"

Comment: You could try giving your credential provider a really low guid in the sort order when placed in the registry.

Comment: This is my question, too. @Edz1o Do you find answer?

Comment: I have not yet found a solution.  If I do I will post the result here.  Please do the same if you do.